# How to change my output data to be in hourly only?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import json
import csv
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

PPT_id = 'S116'


datetime_lst = []
temp_lst = []

filepath_lst = os.listdir('./input/')
for filepath in filepath_lst:
    f = open('./input/' + filepath,'r')
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    f.close()

    for item in data['items']:
        dtime = datetime.strptime(item['timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
        readings = item['readings']
        for read in readings:
            if read['station_id']==PPT_id:
                dtime_str = dtime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H%M')
                dtime = datetime.strptime(dtime_str, '%d/%m/%Y %H%M')
                datetime_lst.append(dtime)
                temp_lst.append(read['value'])
                continue
            
out = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime':datetime_lst, 'Temperature':temp_lst}, columns=['Datetime','Temperature'])
out.to_csv('temperature.csv', index=False)
```

Currently, this is my code, and my output into Excel yields the time in hours and minutes. I would just like to have the hourly data whereby the timing is just 01:00 02:00 and not like the example below where minutes are included, how would I edit my code?

```
01/08/2022  00:02:00
01/08/2022  00:03:00
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
out['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(out['Datetime'])
out['Datetime']=out['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%H-%M')
```

full code:

```
import json
import csv
import os
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

PPT_id = 'S116'


datetime_lst = []
temp_lst = []

filepath_lst = os.listdir('./input/')
for filepath in filepath_lst:
    f = open('./input/' + filepath,'r')
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    f.close()

    for item in data['items']:
        dtime = datetime.strptime(item['timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ') # ----- > old one: %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z
        readings = item['readings']
        for read in readings:
            if read['station_id']==PPT_id:
                dtime_str = dtime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H%M')
                dtime = datetime.strptime(dtime_str, '%d/%m/%Y %H%M')
                datetime_lst.append(dtime)
                temp_lst.append(read['value'])
                continue
            
out = pd.DataFrame({'Datetime':datetime_lst, 'Temperature':temp_lst}, columns=['Datetime','Temperature'])
out['Datetime']=out['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')
'''
%Y: year
%m: month
%d: day
%H: hour
%M: minute

you can change "dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')" field to whatever format you want.

'''
out.to_csv('temperature.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: for item in data['items']:
        dtime = datetime.strptime(item['timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
        readings = item['readings']
        for read in readings:
            if read['station_id']==PPT_id:
                df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
                df['date']=df['date'].dt.strftime('%H-%M')
                datetime_lst.append(dtime)
                temp_lst.append(read['value'])
                continue
            
Slotted it in here, however got the error that df is not defined, possible to elaborate on ur code?

Comment: you should use the code at the end. I updated the answer, can you check it?

Comment: Jan-53 28.7
Jan-54 28.7
Jan-55 28.7
Jan-56 28.7
Jan-57 28.7
Jan-58 28.7
Jan-59 28.7
02-00 28.8
02-Jan 28.8
02-Mar 28.8
02-Jun 28.8
Now it looks like this, which is a bit weird

Comment: Finally, can you try this: `out['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(out['Datetime'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')`  i updated answer again. Can you check ?  If not, I think you need to provide a sample data.

Comment: still not working well, got my json file from https://data.gov.sg/dataset/realtime-weather-readings?resource_id=17494bed-23e9-4b3b-ae89-232f87987163 in order to run the program

Comment: I tried with a sample data. it worked for me with no errors. Frankly, I don't understand what output you want, but I edited my answer. There you can set the format you want yourself. I also made a small change in the for loop because it was giving me an error. I marked with " **---->** " symbol.